# what is the gradle command to run @RunWith(Parameterized::class) android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I have implemented espresso parameterized tests using kotlin but could not find gradle command to run , working fine if i use adb instrument command.  but ./gradlew connectedAndroidTest does not run these tests

```
@RunWith(Parameterized::class)
class ClassA (){

@Test
  fun testmethod()
{
   // logic
}

 companion object {
    @JvmStatic
    @Parameterized.Parameters
    fun oAuthrguments() = arrayOf()
   }

}
```